# Copying constraints in IloCplex C++

Tags: c++, cplex

At some point of my code, I need to extract the cuts which I have added to model A and add them to model B. These two models are in different environment. I tried this

```
for(int i=0; i<A.cuts.getSize(); i++)
   B.cuts.add(IloRange(env, A.cuts[i].getLB(), A.cuts[i].getExpr(), models[t].cuts[i].getUB()));
```

and it does not work because it does not map the variables correctly.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Is it a requirement that the two models are in different environments?

Comment: Hi rkersh, yes they should be in separate env due to the parallelization